# Scroll detection fails with a wrapper set to overflow: scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, wrapper, jquery-waypoints

I have been implementing the amazing panelSnap plugin (http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/) into my site. This works fine.
However to implement a menu, you must put all the sections inside a wrapper, with the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This works fine. However it immediately causes Waypoints to fail (currently being used with animate.css to fade in elements on scroll).

As you can see in the jsFiddle, it seems as if the browser no longer detects scrolling to display the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/beechboy707/uk30azcm/4/

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas please? Basically jQuery Waypoints fails when the container of all page content is set to overflow: scroll. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [context option](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/context-option/) to your wrapper.

```
$('.whatever').waypoint(function () {
  // do stuff
}, {
  context: '#wrapper'
})
```